# Advice needed based on cloudwatch metrics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm in dilemma regarding which instance type we should be using for our development server. This server is used to test our code before it goes to our production server.

This server is also used by our employees for their day to day task such as bug reporting, status filling and similar tasks.

---

OS: `Ubuntu 16.04`

Server: `nginx+php-fpm`

Current Instance type: `c5d.large`

Last 2 weeks average CPU utilization:

[image: 2weeks average cpu utilization]

All cloudwatch metrics based on last 2 weeks:
[image: All cloudwatch metrics based on last 2 weeks]

Comment: Mostly idle, with peaks. Sounds like a t3 instance could be cost effective, if you can tolerate the use of EBS rather than directly attached SSD.

Comment: I'm thinking about trying t3.medium.
Which parameters should I let you know so that you can advice whether I should be going with SSD or not?

Comment: General Purpose SSD is the default storage option anyway. Is it any different from directly attached SSD as you said?

Comment: t3 instances have EBS disk, which is disk across a high speed network. It's fairly fast, but not near as fast as directly attached SSD. No-one can really answer your questions, you need to try it with your own application / workload.